# Visual Studio for Mac Android Emulator Error with M1 Chip

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

New to developing on a Mac.  Trying to get the Android Emulator to run.  I have the newest MacBook Air with the M1Chip. When I go to run the simulator for Android I get this warning and the emulator never launches:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(5,5): Warning: An exception occurred while validating the Java SDK installation in '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-1.jdk/Contents/Home' that was found while searching the paths from 'monodroid-config.xml'. Ensure that the Android section of the Visual Studio options has a valid Java SDK directory configured. To use a custom SDK path for a command line build, set the 'JavaSdkDirectory' MSBuild property to the custom path. Exception: Not a directory
Parameter name: homePath (NoteTaker.Android)
```

Comment: VS --> Preferences --> Projects --> SDK Locations --> Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the Java SDK is either incorrect or the SDK is corrupt.

First you should download the latest version of the Java SDK from the [Oracle Website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/).

Then within Visual Studio you need to navigate to *Preferences > Projects > SDK Locations > Android > Locations*.

You will need to update the Java SDK path to the new SDK you downloaded.

e.g /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/**SDK17**/Contents/Home